# Datasets for cache hit-rate evaluation

Tags: caching, dataset, computer-science, benchmarking, trace

I'm implementing a new eviction strategy for caches. In order to compare its hit ratio to a regular LRU cache, I would like to use data traces from actual systems (like server requests or virtual memory accesses), that I can replay with my cache and measure needed metrics.
Surprisingly, I found very few such traces, the biggest one is Wikipedia access traces.

What are other sources for such traces? 
What are common benchmarks for evaluating cache efficiency?

Comment: For CPU caches, you can run workloads under the GEM5 simulator; I assume SPECint / SPECfp are common.  IDK if it lets you record traces for later replay.  http://gem5.org/Main_Page.  It can simulate a multiple different ISAs, and even full-system simulation for a few including x86 and ARM.